# Recover only part of the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, entity-framework-5

I'm trying develop a model form and insert my view in it, like this.

[image: Model form]

But the Entity FrameWork is bring all the view with menus and footer, like this.

[image]

How remove menus and footer the view and have only fields and labels?

### The view

```
    @model TPTMVC.Models.User
@using TPTMVC.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        <div class="display-label">FirstName</div>
        <div class="display-field">@Model.FirstName</div>

        <div class="display-label">LastName</div>
        <div class="display-field">@Model.LastName</div>

        <div class="display-label">Number</div>
        <div class="display-field">@((Model.billingDetail).Number)</div>

        <div class="display-label">Owner</div>
        <div class="display-field">@((Model.billingDetail).Owner)</div>


    </fieldset>
}
```

### Tretch controller

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            User user = context.User.Single(x => x.UserId == id);
            return View(user);
        }
```

### Inserting view into model form

Link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "Details" })
```

Jquery

```
$(".Details").live(
    "click", function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); use this or return false
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $("#dialog-view").dialog({
        title: 'Detail User',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            direction: "up"
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });

    $("#dialog-view").dialog('open');

    return false;

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I'm develop in Entity Framework.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need to look into partial views

Comment: .live() --> version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a `PartialView` instead of `View`

```
public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            User user = context.User.Single(x => x.UserId == id);
            return PartialView("Details", user);
        }
```

Comment: WannaCSharp, dont work.                                                   public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            User user = context.User.Single(x => x.UserId == id);
            return PartialView(user);
        }

Comment: WannaCSharp, same result.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for all.